# Compute the dependency graph for a set of instructions

Tags: compiler-construction

In a sequence of possible instructions:

```
1: A[i] = B[i]
2: B[i] = A[i] + D[i - 1]
3: C[i] = A[i] - D[i - 1]
4: D[i] = B[i] + C[i]
```

I want to compute the dependency graph that will end up looking like:

### [image]

What would be an efficient algorithm for doing so?

My current implementation looks like this:

- Run through all of the instructions and generate `last_seen` array.

  A: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5DzY.png),
  B: [2],
  C: [3],
  D: [4]
- For every instruction iff is assignment:

  - Split into `left` and `right` parts
  - Generate new `node(left)`.
  - for every identifier in `right`: make new `edge(left, last_seen[right])`

Answer (score 3):

In the book advanced compiler design and implementation by Steven Muchnick [Advanced Compiler Design and Implementation](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=sv&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=advanced%20compiler%20design%20and%20implementation&btnG=&oq=advanced%20compiler%20d#d=gs_cit&u=%2Fscholar%3Fq%3Dinfo%3AurVpQKT6bVsJ%3Ascholar.google.com%2F%26output%3Dcite%26scirp%3D0%26hl%3Dsv), algorithm 9.6 presents a method for constructing a dependence DAG for basic block scheduling. It also considers latencies between the different operations (So that instructions later can be selected according to some heuristic).

```
    #= Pseudocode of the build dag procedure (Some simplified ICAN notation)=# 
Build_dag(numberOfInstructions, Instructions)
    begin 
         DAG = {Nodes =  {}, Edges = {}, Label = {}, Roots{}}
         Conflicts = A set of integers representing conflicts
         j, k #= Integers for indexing=#
         for j in 1 to numberOfInstructions
              D.Nodes ∪= {j}
              Conflicts = {}
              for k = 1 to j - 1
                  if Conflict between Instructions[k] and Instructions[j]
                      Conflicts ∪= {k}
                  end
              end
              if isEmpty(Conflicts)
                  DAG.Roots ∪= {j}
              else 
                 for each k in Conflicts
                     DAG.Edges ∪= {k->j} #=Adds an edge between node k and node j=#
                     DAG.Label(k, j) = Latency(Instructions[k], 1, Instructions[j], IssueLatency + 1)
                 end
              end
          end
      return DAG
end
```

The algorithm first need to check conflicts (that is, instructions already present in the DAG)
If there is no conflict, we add node j to the roots of the DAG. Otherwise, we add an edge between *k* and *j* for each conflict *k* if there is a conflict. Some Latency function gives the label.

The time complexity of this method is *O(N²)*